# enter blank value in double type cell in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have Custom table model and also custom rendering for my problematic double column in jtable. I want to have the option to leave blank cell in the double column. In fact when I leave it blank the writing to be null. This option is by default in another string columns but here if I live it blank some exception is thrown. How I can make it?

Edit: this is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at table.MyTableModel.setValueAt(MyTableModel.java:62)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2710)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4712)
```

here is the code in MyTaleModel

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {

    data.get(row)[col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

this is data:  `static ArrayList<Object[]> data`

and this is the column renderer

```
public class ColumnRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

int precision = 0;
Number numberValue;
NumberFormat nf;

public ColumnRenderer(int p_precision) {
    super();
    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    precision = p_precision;
    nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(p_precision);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(p_precision);
}

@Override
public void setValue(Object value) {
    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number)) {
        numberValue = (Number) value;
        value = nf.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
    }
    super.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: "some" exception? A specific exception, occurring at a specific location is thrown. It contains a specific message intended to be read. If you don't understand the stack trace, at least show it us, along with the corresponding code.

Comment: A `NullPointerException` caused by `setValue` should have nothing to do with your cell renderer, it has something to do with the data/model/editor

Comment: you have issue with XxxTableModel, no rellated with renderer somehow,

Answer (score 3):

Not a real answer, but too long to be comment.

There should be no need for a custom renderer if you just want to display `Double` instances. The default renderer is capable of handling that situation. The only precondition is that you return the correct class in your `TableModel` for the `getColumnClass` method.

You can see that the default renderer is sufficient in the source code. A quick copy-paste:

```
static class DoubleRenderer extends NumberRenderer {
    NumberFormat formatter;
    public DoubleRenderer() { super(); }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if (formatter == null) {
            formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        }
        setText((value == null) ? "" : formatter.format(value));
    }
}
```

So you are most likely doing something wrong which you are not telling us. Post the stack trace and relevant code for better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use wrapper class `Double` in place of `double` as primitive type can't be assigned with `null` but wrapper type can be. This is the reason, other cells with different type e.g. `String` are working as `String` can also be assigned to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In you custom cell renderer, you need to take into account what a empty value actually is.  You could return `null` from your table model or a predefined value (such as 0 for example).

If you model is actually return `Double` then it becomes considerably easier...

In you're custom cell render you will need to make a check for the "empty" state...

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (value == null) {
        value = "";
    } else {
        // Carry on as normal...
    }
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
```